Can I safely upgrade my battery as long as I am within the voltage and current ratings of the motor? (amp limit vs watt rating)
TLDR: The real question is "Does voltage have any thermal effect on a wire with the same current?" Cause if not.. then the answer to the title question I think would be "yes" and I don't believe anything else below matters except for the 2nd table.
The background why this became a question for me:
I have an 8 KW Hub Motor with the following specifications:

Rated Power: 800 0W
Max Power: 11250 W (Peak 16000 W)
Rated Voltage: 72 V
Continuous current: 130 A
Max current:190 A, Peak 260 A
Winding Core material: Aluminum
Working Temperature: 70 °C, Peak 120 °C

If I take the power ratings and divide them by the rated amps (Volts * Amps = Watts) I get the following voltages:



Stated rating
130A
190A
260A




8000W
61.5V
42.1V
30.7V


11250W
70.3V
59.2V
43.2V


16000W
123V
84.2V
61.5V



But if my understanding is correct.. voltage has no effect on the thermal limits whereas current does. In that case, the power ratings don't really make sense to me when I calculate the limits based on the rated current and rated voltage, especially if you consider each phase of the motor can take the rated current:




130A
190A
260A




QS Motors
8000W
11250W
16000W


72V * amps
9360W
13680W
18720W


72V * 3 phases * amps
28080W
41040W
56160W



(my battery can output 10kw and I have my controller set to output 700A which is 14v and it doesn't melt my windings or burn out my hall sensors which is why I believe the actual current limit is: current rating * 3)
The only thing that refutes that understanding though was watching Styropyro's video of 100 car batteries where he changed the configuration from 12 V to 60 V and had better success melting things. Which is why I'm worried if I upgraded my battery to do 20 kW, would 72 V at 280 A (above motor stated 260 A limit) be problematic?
Is it just me or are power ratings mostly just marketing speak? And with that in mind, could I safely upgrade my battery as long as the output from the controller is within the voltage and current ratings of the motor?


Does voltage have any thermal effect on a wire with the same amperage?

No. Thermal heating of a wire depends only on the current through the wire.

Cause if not.. then the answer to the title question I think would be "yes"

That is correct.

Can I safely upgrade my battery as long as I am within the voltage and amperage ratings of the motor? (amp limit vs watt rating)

Yes. There are other factors to consider as well, especially the capacity of the battery (i.e. amp-hours), whether the battery permits deep cycling etc. But if all the other factors are the same or better, you will be fine.

The only thing that refutes that understanding though was watching Styropyro's video of 100 car batteries where he changed the configuration from 12v to 60v and had better success melting things. Which is why I'm worried if I upgraded my battery to do 20KW, would 72v at 280A (above motor stated 260A limit) be problematic?

If you apply a higher voltage across a section of a conductor, as is done in Styropyro's video, one will get more current and the higher current will cause higher heating. In this case the wire is the load. But in normal use, wire is used to connect power to a load. The voltage across the wire is, in normal use, NOT the voltage across the load, but rather is only the current through the wire times the resistance of the wire.

Thanks for the reassurance and explanation of the wire being the load! That didn't occur to me. My battery will likely be 72v 180ah with around 280A continuous output. It won't reach the higher ends of the motor, but will exceed what it is "rated" for.
